# Products in orders are hidden opencart 2.x

Tags: e-commerce, open-source, opencart2.x, product

Im using opencart 2.1.0.1, everything was okay but now, when there is a new order, products are not showing! Everything else is okay except that the products are not there! I will attach screen to be more clear. [see pic here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJs4z.png)

Comment: what changed between "then" and "now"? New theme? New extension? New VQMOD? Something had to have changed...

Comment: Nothing, really nothing! Thats the problem, what can happen and how can i trace the problem?